# Frattini subgroup of $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, maximal-subgroup, frattini-subgroup

Suppose $G$ is a finite, non-trivial $p$-group and $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup, defined as the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$. Since $G$ is finite, there are finitely many maximal subgroups, $M_1, ..., M_k$.
My goal is to show that $M_1 \cap ... \cap M_{j-1} \cap M_{j+1} \cap ... \cap M_k \setminus M_j$ is non-empty for each $j = 1,..., k$. I was able to prove that any maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal and has index $p$. But, it is not clear how to proceed.
I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: It's not true. Take the Klein 4-group, with three maximal subgroups. The intersection of any two is trivial, so if you remove the elements from the third you get the empty set. In fact, it is false for any noncyclic $p$-group, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The last past of Arturo's comment is also correct. If $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then $G/\phi(G)$ is elementary abelian. And then, in $Z_p^n$ with $n\geq 2$, if you take the intersection of all subgroups of index $p$ except 1, you always get the identity. (This is easy to show.) It's well known that $n=1$ if and only if the group is cyclic. (This follows by Burnside's Basis Theorem, for example, although it might be even easier.)

Comment: @verret You can use the fact that the Frattini subgroup is the set of nongenerators, and take an element that maps to a generator of the quotient.